# Time out on lost connection in Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I need to handle connectivity problems correctly while executing long-running commands over SSH with Paramiko.

The `exec_command` has a `timeout` argument but it throws an exception if there is no response. So it raises when the connection is lost as well as when a command you execute works longer than a `timeout` seconds.

So I tried to use `set_keepalive` but this does not work either. Paramiko does not guarantee that the keepalive packet is sent and it seems that it does not check the keepalive response from the server. I simply put:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s ... -j DROP
```

on a target server in the middle of a command executes and watched Paramiko's debug logs - it just keeps sending keepalive packet and does not pay attention at the absence of a server response. So it seems there is nothing similar to `openssh` `ServerAliveCountMax` param which will kill ssh if there so no response to the client from the ssh server.

As I see there is no way to distinguish long running command and a network failure. I can put a `timeout` on `exec_command` call and believe that if an exception is raised it's not a slow command but a connection loss.

Is there any solid way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Both cases are network failures, one is that it didn't work from start, the other one because it failed later. In the end there is no much difference between them.

It is up to you to decide how your code behaves in this case. The usual approach is to retry by inserting a growing timeout.

The most famous algorithm for this is called [Exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

Comment: What? The problem is that I can't understand if there is no connection to the server or the command I execute is just hanging. `exec_command('sleep 5', timeout=2)` will always die, because the timeout param isn't about the connection timeout, it's all about the total time spent executing this statement. I want it to die only if there is no network for x seconds.